# Does CSS :before and :after for background shadows work as well with fixed elements for creating page curl effects

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, page-curl

I have a element I would like to shadows to create a page curl effect with using before and after css properties. I have done this else where on an item that has relative positioning. This works fine and was done like this:

```
.feed li{
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:10%;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:20px;
    overflow:visible;
    background:#FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.feed li:before, .feed li:after{
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    height: 10px;
    content: ' ';
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 12px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: -1;
}
.feed li:after{
    left:auto;
    right: 0px;
    top:12px;
    bottom:auto;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 -6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

However when I use a similar method on an object the z-index appears to be overridden and has my shadows appear on top of the element instead of behind it. This is what I have for this:

```
    .nav{
    z-index:1;
    position:fixed;
    background:#FFF;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:200px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.nav:before,.nav:after{
    content:'';
    position:fixed;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: -1;
    width:195px;
    height:50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.nav:before{
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform:  rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform:  rotate(-2deg);
    -o-transform:  rotate(-2deg);
    transform:  rotate(-2deg);
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.nav:after{
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(2deg);
    -moz-transform:  rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform:  rotate(2deg);
    -o-transform:  rotate(2deg);
    transform:  rotate(2deg);
    bottom:auto;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is here, I have done this method on other items without any problems. The only I can thnik of is that fixed elements are affected differently to others.

Comment: Way too much code, please follow the guidelines and create short and precise code, that people will want to read. Use this link for reference: http://sscce.org.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/86FhF/1)

Referring to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content):

> The :before and :after pseudo-elements interact with other boxes as if they were real elements inserted just inside their associated element.

That means they lie on another stack relative to the parent. It is possible to position them behind the parent though. That's done by adding a negative z-index like you did.

But it seems like there's a problem putting those pseudo elements behind the parents background (if it has one). As a solution it is suggested to add `z-index:1;` and `position:relative;` to the parent. That's why your first example works fine while the one with `position:fixed;` causes problems.

In my solution I changed the markup:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="shadows"></div>
</div>
```

and applied appropriate rules to the elements. I don't know how you imagined the navigation to look in the end, but I think my solution looks great. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/86FhF/1).

Comment: I didn't think doing that but it does work really well and looks clean too. Thanks